# How to put different text in a message that is being printed from a loop

Tags: java, loops

I am very new to Java and as such I am not too familiar with much of the lingo. I am sure someone has asked this before but I can't seem to figure out what phrase to search.

Anyways, my problem is that I am currently working on an assignment where I generate 5 random numbers, display them, add them up, and see if the number is prime. While I don't know how to do much of that, my problem is actually with displaying the randomly generated numbers. I'm not sure how to put code in here so I'll just copy and paste mine.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int sim = 0;
  System.out.print("The five random numbers are: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    sim += (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;
    System.out.print(sim + ", ");
  }
}
```

Now my issue is, I'm trying to get it to display results like "The five random numbers are: 3, 6, 7, 10, and 12."

But instead I'm getting "The five random numbers are: 3, 6, 7, 10, 12," So how would I put the and and such into it while it's being generated by a loop? Would I need to have a separate loop or something? Sorry if this question is dumb, I'm just very lost on this project altogether.

Comment: Simply manipulate the output display of the final number:

if (i == 4) { System.out.println("and " + sim); }
else { System.out.print(sim + ", "); }

Comment: Ahh this is a little bit more streamlined,I didn't think of switching around the order like that, makes sense. I'll try it out! Also any idea on how I'd add the numbers up?

Comment: you are already adding the numbers together with "sim += ..."  Your question suggests that this is not what you want! If so, add another variable, say "int sumSim".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer with @DevilsHnd's solution:

```
int sim = 0;
int nb=4;

System.out.print("The five random numbers are: ");
for (int i = 0; i <= nb; i++)
{
    sim += (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;

    if ( i < nb ) {
        System.out.print(sim + ", ");
    } else {
        System.out.print("and " + sim + ".");
    }
}
```

#### I get the feeling that `sim +=` is an error.

If you wish to print the random number AND add them together, you may need an additional variable:

```
int sumSum=0;
int nb=4;

System.out.print("The five random numbers are: ");
for (int i = 0; i <= nb; i++)
{
    int sim = (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;
    sumSum += sim;

    if ( i < nb ) {
        System.out.print(sim + ", ");
    } else {
        System.out.print("and " + sim + ".");
    }
}
```

I added:

- int sumSum=0;
- sumSum += sim;

`sumSum` is not being printed, but holds the sum of the 5 numbers.

Comment: Thanks @DevilsHnd, missed the 'and' part! Fixed it.

Comment: hmm, so I did that and then I tried an else statment to add in the "and" but that added one at the very end too...

Comment: see the updated answer, this prints (for example) "2, 3, 6, 9, and 10."

Comment: Oh okay, I sent my question right after you corrected it. I really appreciate the help! Now if I may ask another question, when it comes to adding them together, I'm slightly confused on how to do it. Since they're just reassigning the variable instead of assigning new ones I cant just do (a + b + c + d + e) to get my answer.

Comment: Very nice but I think it would have been easier to just do as I had commented on the original post. Mind you using the variable instead of a magic number as Alex has done is the better way to go.

Comment: Okay I didn't mean to send the last one yet, and I can't figure out how to edit. I'm feeling like an idiot. Anyways you don't have to straight up tell me or anything but I'm not sure where to even start on this one. I appreciate any help and all the help so far.

Comment: In fact @DevilsHnd, I do prefer your if-else :)  It's just that I won't steal your solution...

Comment: @senpaimaster I think what you are wondering is if you could just store the random number in variables, and then print them all in a single command ?

Comment: @Alex Well no I'm trying to have the program take the five random numbers and add them together, assign the sum to a variable, and display it. I just don't even know where to start on figuring out how to add them together.

Comment: you ARE adding them together with your "sim += ..."

Comment: I changed the answer to a community wiki and include DevilsHnd solution

Comment: How does that work then? I must not understand something then. For example if the five random numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, then the sum of those is 15. Where is this number being stored if it's adding them together? I thought everytime the loop ran it was reassigning the variable sim and then printing it out. I'm not sure I understand how they're being added?

Comment: in your original code, 'sim += randomNumber' is the same as 'sim = sim + randomNumber'. I think you want to remove the '+' so that sim only equals the randomNumber. Then, you can use another variable 'sumSim' for the sum. Home I'm being clear.

Comment: Yes I understand! Programming is so frustrating but every time you learn something new it's pretty damn fun. I  think I can figure out how to determine if it's prime or not, or at least I'll go try my best. I really appreciate your help Alex! Great first impression of these forums too, really helpful and I for sure know more now. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int sim = 0;
  System.out.print("The five random numbers are: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    sim += (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;
    if(i==3){
      System.out.print(sim + " and ");
    }
    else{
    System.out.print(sim + ", ");
    }
  }
}
```

Add a condition to check the second last number and in that case add `and` instead of `,`.